# replace text with jsx component in response

Tags: reactjs

as part of an application I query a server for some information.
The server replies with some arbitrary text which may or may not contain some code wrapped in backticks (```).
I want to replace this backticked delimited code with a syntax highlighted version.
My current attempt is:

````
 function processResponse(response) {


  const codeRegex = /```([\s\S]*?)```/g;
    let resp = response

    let formattedResponse = response.replace(codeRegex, (x, code: string) => {
      const language = (x.match(/```(.*)\n/) || [])[1] || "none";
      return (<SyntaxHighlighter language={language} style={dark}>
        {code}
      </SyntaxHighlighter>)
    });
    return formattedResponse;
  }
````

but obviously this returns the string [Object object] instead of syntax highlighted code.
This is because I'm trying to use a string function to add objects.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `createElement`.

From the [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement)

```
const element = createElement(type, props, ...children)
```

Example

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-estrela-z6w9hi?file=/App.js

Comment: thank you for the answer! how would i match and replace specific text tho?